# Where is the configuration file in g-wan?

Tags: php, web, web-applications, configuration, g-wan

Where is the configuration file (init.d) in g-wan. Also how do I get rid of the '?' In the url to run php or c script ( I think you need to change this in the configure)?

Comment: **/etc/init.d** files are shell scripts that respond to start, stop, restart, and reload commands to manage a particular service. G-WAN provides an example of such a script: http://www.gwan.ch/faq#service

Answer (score 1):

As Ken explained, there's no configuration file - but G-WAN scripts (`servlets`, `handlers`), including the `init.c` and `main.c` G-WAN startup scripts, can modify G-WAN by-default settings... even dynamically, during the life of the server, and sometimes on a per-request basis.

Here are the options that can be changed *before* G-WAN starts listening (they are documented in the PDF manual and [on the G-WAN Web site](http://www.gwan.ch/api#env)):

```
 US_SERVER_DATA   // global server pointer for user-defined data
 SERVER_SOFTWARE  // "Server: G-WAN" HTTP response header
 SCRIPT_TMO       // time-out in ms running a script
 KALIVE_TMO       // time-out in ms for HTTP keep-alives
 REQUEST_TMO      // time-out in ms waiting for request
 MIN_SEND_SPEED   // send rate in bytes/sec (if < close)
 MIN_READ_SPEED   // read rate in bytes/sec (if < close)
 MAX_ENTITY_SIZE  // maximum POST entity size
 QUERY_CHAR       // replace '?' by - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )
 USE_WWW_CACHE    // enable static  cache (default: off)
 USE_CSP_CACHE    // enable servlet cache (default: off)
 CACHE_ALL_WWW    // load all /www in cache (default: off)
 USE_MINIFYING    // enable JS/CSS/HTML minifying (default: off)
```

And here is how to change the default query character '?':

```
   u8 *query_char = (u8*)get_env(argv, QUERY_CHAR);
   if(query_char) 
   {
      u8 old = *query_char;
      *query_char = '!'; // "/!hello.c" instead of "/?hello.c"
      printf("> changed query_char from '%c' to '%c' (%p)\n", 
             old, *query_char, query_char);
   }
```

To completely remove the '?' (rather than replacing it) you will have to use a G-WAN connection handler, see [this example just doing what you want](http://www.gwan.ch/developers#handler) on tab #2 'connection handlers'.

In many cases, dynamic settings are preferable to fixed options, like for adaptive timeouts (fixed timeouts leave a server vulnerable to timing attacks, like `Slowloris`).

Comment: I don't want to change it. I want to remove it. Do there no directorship character

Comment: Then write a G-WAN handler to add it for a specific list of dynamic URLs (that clients will use without specifying any '?'). That's what other servers do with regex engines.

Comment: u8 *query_char = (u8*)get_env(argv, QUERY_CHAR); if(query_char) { u8 old = *query_char; *query_char = ''; // "/!hello.c" instead of "/?hello.c" printf("> changed query_char from '%c' to '%c' (%p)\n", old, *query_char, query_char); }

Comment: Empty characters are a syntax error in C. And if it were not the case, G-WAN would then not process any dynamic request since that's the query character that defines one.

Comment: So how would you do it. Sorry I a novice

Comment: Added it to the solution above, the link is http://www.gwan.ch/developers#handler, check the 2nd tab called 'connection handler'. Can you accept the answer above now?

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration "file" per se.  For example, port and IP address are configured as folder names (e.g., 172.16.42.2:8080/...) under the root gwan folder.

Servlets, whether written in php or C or whatever you choose, are in the .../csp folder under the IP:port path under the gwan folder.  With G-WAN, by default, the path to a servlet begins with '?' followed by the servlet name AND extension (e.g., '.php'), and the first parameter is preceded by '&' like the 2nd - nth parameter is with most web servers.

You can change virtually ANYTHING you want about the URL, path, special characters, etc. in a handler, which you can also write in C/C++, etc.  Handlers are in the .../handler folder under the IP:port path under the gwan folder.  What you are asking about specifically is a form of URL-rewriting, and can be done in a handler via a simple string-replacement function (see the examples that come with G-WAN).

There are MANY examples of servlets in the .../csp folder, and several examples of handlers in the .../handler folder.  Most likely you can choose among those and modify them to meet your needs.

FYI, typical naming convention used with G-WAN to disable something at a folder level is to precede it with '_' (e.g., _0.0.0.0:8080/...), and for an individual file to be disabled it is postfixed with '_' (e.g., hello.c_).

The G-WAN developers page has a Connection Handler [URL-rewrite example](http://gwan.com/developers#tab2) that (I think) does what you want.  The specific code to rewrite an incoming request URL (containing no "?") with a URL that references a specific G-WAN servlet (and contains the "?") looks like this:

```
// rewrite /blog requests into /?blog requests
xbuf_replfrto(read_xbuf, read_xbuf->ptr, read_xbuf->ptr + 16, "/blog", "/?blog");
```

See http://gwan.com/developers#tab2 for the complete example.  You will need to create a similar Connection Handler (or just copy the example code and change to meet you needs), and then place that Handler code in the .../handlers path under the IP:port path under the gwan root folder.

Sorry I can't be more specific with a PHP example; I've done all my G-WAN work in C/C++ so far.

Comment: So exactly how do I get rid of the ? In the url

Comment: I'm not at my computer at the moment, but there is an example either online or in the gwan package for changing a URL from /blog to /?blog.c or something like that.  Very close to what you want.  Have you looked under FAQ or API or Developers on the gwan web site?

Comment: Thanks I will have a look. But if you get a chance I will appreciate it if you could give an examplanation/ example. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt, I added a link to a URL-rewrite example that I think is what you are trying to do.  It allows the client (e.g., browser) to request a URL that contains no "?", and rewrites the URL in place so that the request goes to a Servlet that has the "?" in the appropriate location (for G-WAN).

Comment: @matt, what exactly causes an error?  Can you update your original question with the specific thing you are trying and the resulting error?